# .NET 4 Task Class Tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, task

.NET 4 has a Class - [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).
It's pretty interesting and I would like to start using it. For example, I would like to create a very simple Task-based files downloader, with the ability to cancel with every download. 
Can anyone introduce me to some sample code of doing that? I would like to have an list of running tasks and would like to be able to cancel any of them.

P.S. *Code sample can be not functioning I just want to know how to use these things in a best way.*

Comment: Uhm.... The link you pasted actually has an example. Is this not what you need?

Comment: I know that MSDN have some examples, but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to be able to cancel one or more tasks, you need to create a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass in the `CancellationToken` of this to each `Task`. If all the `Task`s must be cancelled using the same operation, they can share the same token. If each task can be cancelled independently of the other, you need to have separate `CancellationToken`s. Please check [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) for examples of how to cancel parallel tasks.

Answer (score 6):

Various samples, simple and more advanced, have been given on the various PFX (Parallel Framework Extension)—of which [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) is part—team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Task Parallel Library section of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.100).aspx) with several howtos and examples.